# neighborhood basis on a set

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Given a topological space $(X,\tau)$ I know perfectly what is a neighborhood basis at $x\in X$.

Now suppose that $X$ is just a set, fix a point $x\in X$ and consider a collection $\mathcal B(x)$ of subsets of $X$ containing $x$. What are the properties that I have to check for $B(x)$ in order to ensure that there exists a topology on $X$ such that a local basis at $x$ is $B(x)$?

This question arises from the following consideration. Very often topologies in books are presented in a weird way; the author simply says "Consider on the set $X$ the topology $\tau$ having this particular neighborhood basis". I'd like to check that what he claims to be a "local basis" is indeed a good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a family $\mathscr{B}(x)$ for each $x\in X$, the key thing to check is that if $B_x\in\mathscr{B}(x)$, $B_y\in\mathscr{B}(y)$, and $z\in B_x\cap B_y$, then there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}(z)$ such that $B\subseteq B_x\cap B_y$. This ensures that $\bigcup_{x\in X}\mathscr{B}(x)$ is a base for a topology on $X$.

Comment: Ok, so as in analogy for "ordinary" basis! Clearly I don't have any "covering" condition.

Comment: @manifold: Right: the covering condition is built in by the fact that you have a local base at *each* point.

Comment: I assume you want your neighbourhoods to be open here? In my book neighbourhoods need not be open, and the neighbourhood base could have many non-open members. In that case the conditions would be more complicated.

Comment: @Henno: Yes. For me a local base by definition consists of open nbhds.